# Is this proof regarding series correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'd like to proof that $\sum x_n$ diverges if $\alpha<1$ and:

$\displaystyle\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=1-\alpha/n$, $\alpha>0, n>>1$

if $\alpha<1$ so:

$\alpha/n<1/n$

then:

$\displaystyle\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>1-1/n$

$x_{n+1}>x_n(1-1/n)$

as $n>>1$ so $(1-1/n)>0$

so we have:

$x_{n+1}>x_n$

then $x_n$ is not going to $0$ so $\sum x_n$ diverges.

Comment: Why is $x_n(1-\frac 1 n ) >x_n$? In your first step you got rid of $\alpha$ and that destroys all chances of proving  the result!

Comment: $ x_{n+1}/x_n\to 1$ does NOT imply that $x_n$ cannot converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $0<\alpha <1$ then $x_n\to 0.$

Suppose $0<\alpha <1$ and $2\le k\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\ge k\implies x_{n+1}/x_n=1-\alpha /n.$

Now $ x_k\ne 0$, else $x_{k+1}$ would not exist. So we have $$n>k\implies \ln |x_n|=(\ln |x_k|)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \ln (1-\alpha /j)=$$ $$=(\ln |x_k|)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} (-\alpha /j +O(1/j^2))=$$ $$=(\ln |x_k|)-\alpha\ln n +O(1)=-\alpha\ln n +O(1).$$ So there exist $L,L'>0$ such that $$n> k\implies L'/n^{\alpha}>|x_n|>L/n^{\alpha}.$$ Now for $n>k,$ every $x_n$ has the same sign, so either $$n> k\implies L'/n^{\alpha}>x_n>L/n^{\alpha}$$ or $$n> k\implies -L'/n^{\alpha}<x_n<-L/n^{\alpha}.$$

Comment: Two useful tools: (1). If every $b_n\ge 0$ then $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}(1+b_n)<\infty$ iff $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} b_n$ converges.... (2). If every $c_n\in [0,1)$ then $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}(1-c_n) >0$ iff $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} c_n$ converges. From (2) with $c_n=\alpha /n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, you can see at once that if $0<\alpha <1$ then $x_n\to 0$ because $\sum_n \alpha /n$ will not converge.

Comment: why is it not true? as the terms are always getting greater as the index goes

Comment: @DaviAmérico. $|x_n|$ is $decreasing.$ $|x_{n+1}|=(1-\alpha /n)|x_n|<|x_n|.$